# When I play a second video, only a freezed frame of the first video is shown and the audio plays

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

My App has a Fragment that's playing videos that are one second long. After a video is played the user has to press a button and then a new video is supposed to be played. Before playing the second video the my main activity loads creates a new fragment and creates new Exoplayer instance.

The first time I play the video everything works as expected. If I however want to play a second video, it shows a freezed image of the last frame of the first video and plays the sound of the second video.
This bug doesn't appear on Android 8 (API level 26) but on versions below Android 8 (I tested Android 6 and Android 7.1).

Given that I have both a new Surface with the new Fragment and a new Exoplayer it's a mystery to me why there's still data for the last frame of the previous video. 
Is there some function I can call to delete that data and get the behavior I get in Android 8 where the second video plays without problems also in earlier versions of Android?

Before I used ExoPlayer the normal MediaPlayer had the same issue. I created a [minimized example](https://github.com/ChristianKleineidam/VideoProblems) of the problem where I have:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button mButton = findViewById(R.id.button1);
        mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                createNewFragment();
            }
        });
    }

    private void createNewFragment() {
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.add(R.id.contentFragment, new VideoFragment());
        ft.commit();
    }
}

public class VideoFragment extends Fragment implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{
    private Context mContext;
    private SimpleExoPlayer mPlayer;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.videolayout, container, false);
        SurfaceView mSurfaceView = (SurfaceView) view.findViewById(R.id.surface_view1);
        SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder = mSurfaceView.getHolder();
        surfaceHolder.setSizeFromLayout();
        surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);

        mContext = inflater.getContext();

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        BandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
        TrackSelection.Factory videoTrackSelectionFactory = new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter);
        TrackSelector trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(videoTrackSelectionFactory);

        mPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(mContext, trackSelector);
        mPlayer.setVideoSurfaceHolder(holder);
        mPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
        playVideo(mContext);
    }

    private void playVideo(Context context){
        final RawResourceDataSource rawResourceDataSource = new RawResourceDataSource(context);

        int raw_res_id = context.getResources().getIdentifier(
                "collect",
                "raw",
                context.getPackageName());
        DataSpec dataSpec = new DataSpec(RawResourceDataSource.buildRawResourceUri(raw_res_id));
        try {
            rawResourceDataSource.open(dataSpec);

            DataSource.Factory factory = new DataSource.Factory() {
                @Override
                public DataSource createDataSource() {
                    return rawResourceDataSource;
                }
            };
            MediaSource media_source = new ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(factory).createMediaSource(rawResourceDataSource.getUri());
            mPlayer.prepare(media_source);

        } catch (RawResourceDataSource.RawResourceDataSourceException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to do the below code for fragmentchange

```
 final FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    Fragment f = new VideoFragment();
    transaction.replace(R.id.contentFragment, f).commit();
```

Just try this code and check if same occurs